# Which ubuntu AMI should I choose to create a new EC2 instance? What are the advantage and disadvantages?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ubuntu-14.04

I want to set up an ec2 instance which runs Ubuntu 14.04

There are two possible set of candidates of AMI:

From the Quick Start menu

[image]

vs from Ubuntu

[image]

What should I consider before I make a choice? Are they basically identical?

One concern I have regarding the ubuntu community AIMs is this: As i can see in this url here, https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/, the 14.04 TLS AMIs seem to be rebuilt regularly. Does it mean that, shall I decide to set up a new ec2 in the future, I might not be able to baseline on the same AMI as available now because they could be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a host from an AMI you can create a snapshot of the volume (should be done before starting the instance to avoid having irrelevant state on the disk), and create a new AMI from that snapshot. Then you have your own AMI with the same contents.

As for which one to choose, there are only two 14.04 images available: [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) (presumably PV) and [HVM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html). Which one is best for you depends on your requirements.